# How can I return the index of the scatter using js callback?

Tags: python, bokeh, bokehjs

I am trying to create a JS callback to return the index of the scatter I created. But seems like the output is always “undefined”. Could anyone help me what is wrong with my code?

here is a short example:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure


# create some data
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                                    y=[6, 7, 8, 9, 10],color=["navy", "orange", "olive", "firebrick", "gold"]))

# create a plot with circles
plot = figure()
plot.circle('x', 'y', size=10, source=source, color = 'color')

# create the JavaScript callback
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""  
    
    // get the index of the selected point
    var index = source.selected.indices[0];
    
    // alert the index
    alert(index);
""")

# add the callback to the plot
plot.js_on_event('tap', callback)

# show the plot
show(plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to evaluate the callback object `cb_obj` to get information about the `pan` action.

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    console.log(cb_obj['x'], cb_obj['y']);
    // alert(cb_obj['x'], cb_obj['y']);
""")
```

Be careful, because this will not return the position of the circle renederer. This will return the position of the click event. This event will also be triggered if no renderer is close to the click.